# Java Regex of String start with number and fixed length

Tags: java, regex

I made a regular expression for checking the length of String , all characters are numbers and start with number e.g 123
Following is my expression

```
REGEX =^123\\d+{9}$";
```

But it was unable to check the length of String. It validates those strings only their length is 9 and start with 123.
But if I pass the String 1234567891 it also validates it. But how should I do it which thing is wrong on my side.

Comment: Get rid of the `+`: `REGEX =^123\\d{6}$";`

Comment: The word *validate* better describes what you're trying to accomplish. You're trying to *validate* the length of the string to contain exactly 9 digits after the prefix "123".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like already answered here, the simplest way is just removing the `+`:

```
^123\\d{9}$
```

or

```
^123\\d{6}$
```

Depending on what you need exactly.

You can also use another, a bit more complicated and generic approach, a negative lookahead:

```
(?!.{10,})^123\\d+$
```

Explanation:

This: `(?!.{10,})` is a **negative look-ahead** (`?=` would be a positive look-ahead), it means that if the expression after the look-ahead matches this pattern, then the overall string doesn't match. Roughly it means: *The criteria for this regular expression is only met if the pattern in the negative look-ahead doesn't match*.

In this case, the string matches **only** if `.{10}` doesn't match, which means 10 or more characters, so it only matches if the pattern in front matches up to 9 characters.

A positive look-ahead does the opposite, only matching if the criteria in the look-ahead **also** matches.

Just putting this here for curiosity sake, it's more complex than what you need for this.

Comment: your (?!.{10,})^123\\d+$ it is working fine thanks can you elaborate it

Comment: @pcalcao : I want to check if string starts with number and also if it contains special characters. I was able to right regex for special characters

/[\.,\/\\#+!%\^&\*;:{}=`~()\s]/

Now I want to add check if string starts with number too in this regex.

How I can achieve it?

Answer (score 5):

Try using this one:

```
^123\\d{6}$
```

I changed it to `6` because 1, 2, and 3 should probably still count as digits.

Also, I removed the `+`. With it, it would match 1 or more `\d`s (therefore an infinite amount of digits).

Comment: My requirement is any number start with specific number like 123 or 45 or 67 any thing
That mean every time I have to change length parameter depends upon user send me in parameter

Comment: @waseem Then check `str.length() == 9`. However, that wasn't in your original question. Ask a new question if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment below [Doorknobs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958087/java-regex-of-string-start-with-number-and-fixed-length#14958118) you can do this:

```
int length = 9;
String prefix = "123"; // or whatever
String regex = "^" + prefix + "\\d{ " + (length - prefix.length()) + "}$";
if (input.matches(regex)) {
    // good
} else {
    // bad
}
```